# Return the maximum from getting the left or right value of an array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1}
```

I have to multiply the index by the value inside of that inside. I can only take a value from the left or right of the array.

For example:

If I take the number from the left ONLY, I'd have `1x1 + 2x2 + 3x3 + 4x4+ 1x5 + 2x6 + 3*7 + 4x8 + 1x9 = 109 points.`

If I take the number from the right end each time, I'd have `1x1+4x2+3x3+2x4+1x5+4x6+3x7+2x8+1x9 = 101 points`

If I alternated eating from the left and right ends (starting on the left), I'd score `1x1+1x2+2x3+4x4+3x5+3x6+4x7+2x8+1x9 = 111 points`

However, the correct solution is

```
1x1+1x2+2x3+3x4+4x5+1x6+2x7+3x8+4x9 = 121 points
```

My code is super ugly, but can anyone help me with it?

```
public class CandyRoll {
    static int total = 0;
    static int test (List<Integer> list, int index, int multiplier) {
        //Base Case
        if (list.size() < 1) { return -1;}


        if ((list.get(index) * multiplier) == (list.get(list.size() - 1) * multiplier)){
            total = total + list.get(index) * multiplier;
            multiplier++;
            //list.remove(index);
            index++;
            test(list, index, multiplier);
        } else if ((list.get(index) * multiplier) < (list.get(list.size() - 1) * multiplier)) {
            total = total + list.get(index) * multiplier;
            multiplier++;
            //list.remove(index);
            index++;
            test(list, index, multiplier);
        } else if ((list.get(index) * multiplier) > (list.get(list.size() - 1) * multiplier)) {
            total = total + list.get(list.size() - 1) * multiplier;
            multiplier++;
            //list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            index++;
            test(list, index, multiplier);
        }

        //Given example should be 121.
        return total;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(1);

        int index = 0;

        System.out.println(test(list, index, 1));
    }

}
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where is your code having problems?  Show the execution trace against the expected progression of flow and data.  A few strategically-placed print commands should be able to do this.

Comment: I have print cmds that i took away from so its wasnt filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursion in JavaScript:

```js
function f(A, l=0, r=A.length-1, memo={}){
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty([l, r]))
    return memo[[l, r]];

  const i = A.length - (r - l);

  if (l == r)
    return memo[[l, r]] = i * A[l];
  
  return memo[[l, r]] = Math.max(
    i * A[l] + f(A, l + 1, r, memo),
    i * A[r] + f(A, l, r - 1, memo)
  );
}

let A = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1];
console.log(f(A));
```

Comment: As you wrote this, I just figured it out myself!

Comment: @soldfor great (I'm glad the answer didn't spoil it fo you :)

Comment: If you were 10 minutes earlier, it would have

Comment: @גלעדברקן https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781161/how-to-solve-multiple-queries-efficiently Your ideas on this algorithmic problem ? Can you suggest some nice tags so more people see it ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This problem becomes much easier if you make a small mental shift.  Rather than thinking of it as index times the current value, think of it as I take the sum of what is left then remove one value.  So taking `{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1}` and taking numbers from the left only, you would get

```
(1+2+3+4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(  2+3+4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(    3+4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(      4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(        1+2+3+4+1) +
(          2+3+4+1) +
(            3+4+1) +
(              4+1) +
(                1)
```

And alternating would give you:

```
(1+2+3+4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(  2+3+4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(  2+3+4+1+2+3+4  ) +
(    3+4+1+2+3+4  ) +
(      4+1+2+3    ) +
(      4+1+2      ) +
(        1+2      ) +
(        1        )
```

Your optimal solution becomes:

```
 1x1+1x2+2x3+3x4+4x5+1x6+2x7+3x8+4x9

(1+2+3+4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(  2+3+4+1+2+3+4+1) +
(  2+3+4+1+2+3+4  ) +
(    3+4+1+2+3+4  ) +
(      4+1+2+3+4  ) +
(        1+2+3+4  ) +
(          2+3+4  ) +
(            3+4  ) +
(              4  )
```

And so on.

It is easy to verify that this gives the same answer.  But with this switch, we are now recursively solving the original problem for a subarray of the original.  Which makes it much more straightforward to conceptually come up with a dynamic programming solution.  And once you have a conceptual solution, the code can follow.

Comment: so, i can just remove the smallest element, add them, remove the smallest element, etc etc????

Comment: @soldfor Not necessarily.  Sometimes you have to remove a large element so that you can remove a whole sequence of small ones after.  But the point is that you can now write a recursive definition from which you can get DP more easily.

Comment: Nice mental shift.